# How to use Save As function?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm attempting to have my workbook save as a macro-enabled workbook upon execution of my macro. When the macro is initiated, a userform will populate where the user can select a FiscalYear, FormYear, and a FormMonth. The reason for separate years is because FiscalYear will begin in Oct. Oct will be year 18, however it will begin FY19.

I am attempting to insert the value of the FiscalYear into my SaveAs function. The filepath stops after I use FiscalYear and it places the remaining string from the path in front of the DocName I am wanting the workbook to saveas:

Path "J:\x\y\z\FY" & FiscalYear & "\Templates FY" & FiscalYear
DocName:"G22 Dashboard & " " & FormMonth & " " & "FY" & FiscalYear

The document will save in location "FY & FiscalYear &" as "Templates FY18G22 Dashboard & " " FormMonth & " " & "FY" & FiscalYear

Any advice to show me what I am doing incorrectly in this situation?
Probably a rookie mistake, but any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

I have attempted different syntax strategies (use of "" locations, & additions/removals).

```
Sub Save_Report_As()

'Disabling Display Alerts
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Path = "J:\x\y\z\FY" & FiscalYear & "\Templates FY" & FiscalYear
DocName = "G22 Dashboard" & " " & FormMonth & " " & "FY" & FiscalYear

ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs filename:=Path & DocName, FileFormat:=52

'Enabling Display Alerts
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: You need to add the file extension as part of Path string.

Comment: *path & "\" & docname & ".xlsx"* would be more appropriate... you left out the "\" between the path\docname plus the extension (@RyanWildry caught the extension, too)

Comment: @Cyril Good catch. It would sure be helpful to know what is in the FiscalYear variable.

Comment: Thanks for the assist! Still newer to VBA and working out these little kinks. That worked like a charm and I appreciate your guys' help. Final question: In the code I have FileFormat:=52 for a macro-enabled workbook. Is a file extension required on the DocName if I have the FileFormat:=52 in the SaveAs line?

Comment: you need to match the file format to the extension, e.g., .xlsb = fileformat 50, so yes you need both.  see: http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s5/win001.htm

Answer (score 0):

Will post my comment as an answer so this will stop showing up on the "unanswered" list:

*path & "\" & docname & ".xlsx"* would be more appropriate... you left out the "\" between the path\docname plus the extension (@RyanWildry caught the extension, too)